# What if my JRE doesn't support a character encoding?

Tags: java, character-encoding

What if a file is generated using an encoding that my JRE doesn't support? Is there anyway to extend/customize what my JRE can handle?

This might be a terrible/irrelevant example (I'm just brushing up on character sets/encodings for the first time), but I *believe* the Linux JRE does not handle CP-1252 (a Windows encoding). If that's the case, then how can I get a Java app running on a Linux machine to read a CP-1252-encoded file?

Even if the Linux JRE distro *does* support CP-1252 (making that a horrible example), I know for a fact that there are encodings that it doesn't support. Whatever those encodings are, is there any way to extend its standard `Charactset`, and if so, how?

Comment: `CP-1252` is essentially the same as `ISO-8859-1` (and no, I don't think you can add new encodings to the JRE)

Comment: "Sun's Java SE Development Kit 6 for all platforms (SolarisTM operating environment, Linux, and Microsoft Windows) and the Java SE Runtime Environment 6 for Solaris and Linux support all encodings shown on this page." (including Cp1252)  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java class library has a mechanism for adding new character set support; see the javadocs for [`CharsetProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html).

The basic idea is that you write a class that implements the `CharsetProvider` API.  Then in your JAR file you add a file called "/META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider" that lists your charset names, in a prescribed format.

<sub>(I also came across this bug report https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4619777 which might affect you if you are trying to add your own Charsets in a trusted applet ...)</sub>

---

> Do you know of any "Charset Extension libraries" out there that already do this (and provide lots of non-standard charsets)?

The only example I could find is [JCharset](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) and it only adds 8 extra charsets.

If you (or anyone else) needs a charset that is not included, may I suggest that you download JCharset, implement the new charset and then post the changes to the author as patches.

Comment: Thanks @Stepen C (+1) - very interesting...do you know of any "Charset Extension libraries" out there that already do this (and provide lots of non-standard charsets)? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html) says:

> Support for new charsets can be made available via the interface defined in the CharsetProvider class in the java.nio.charset.spi package.

Follow the link and read the instructions...

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet - please see my response under Stephen C's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know of any, no. But the JRE comes with a large listof charsets (see Alan Krueger's comment).

Comment: Thanks again - for what it's worth I did find [JCharset](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/)

Answer (score 0):

sunilkumar from vmoksha

Please check your .xml file containg UTF-8